# Which is better way? Variables related

Tags: tcl

Which is better way:

```
variable var1 $current_file_generation_info::language
```

OR

```
set var1 $current_file_generation_info::language
```

---

Also, which is better way:

```
variable current_file_generation_info::language $var1
```

OR

```
set current_file_generation_info::language $var1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If in a `namespace eval`, use `variable`* to avoid the weirdness of the variable name resolver. (I don't want to describe in detail what it does, other than to say that code that relies on it can be automatically described as buggy and in hard to accurately describe ways.)

If in a procedure, (usually) use `set` **unless** you want a local variable (with the same name as the last component of the namespace variable) that is coupled to the local variable so any manipulation of one is a manipulation of the other. For example, if you do:

```
variable foobar::grill "sprocket"
```

The local variable `grill` will be created and bound to the namespace variable `grill` in the namespace `foobar` (either relative to the current namespace or to the global namespace; this is “namespace resolution” and it is *simpler* than variable resolution, mentioned above!). The namespace variable `grill`, if it didn't already exist, will be specially flagged as existing (but initially unset). Finally, because we did supply a value (`sprocket`) that will be stored into the namespace variable (and hence also appear in the local variable).

If you are going to read or write a namespace variable multiple times in a procedure, it is considerably faster to bind it to a local variable and work on that instead. Once bound, you can't really unbind them, but it is usually not a problem. (Note that the binding process is effectively the same when you use `upvar` or `global` or `namespace upvar`, though each has different ways to look up what it is binding to.)

---

<sup>If you're doing all this to simulate classes, consider using real classes instead. There's a few options (incr Tcl, XOTcl, TclOO, Snit).</sup>

Comment: I need it to use to set variable in different namespace and to use from procedure variable from other namespace and use it inside procedure. Which way is better to use?

Comment: Use `variable ::theothernamespace::thevar; set thevar 123; puts $thevar` and so on.